# Как добавить возможность загрузки аватарки пользователя в его профиле?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Как сделать что бы при нажатии на картинку можно было выбрать аватар на компьютере и он сохранился вместо базового Gravatar'a  и соответственно выводить аватар пользователя в его профиле на сайте, знаю что можно с помощью Theme my login, но не могу понять как, помогите!

Comment: ACF - wordpress

Comment: @Даниил ACF вообще не в тему

Comment: @KAGGDesign почему это?

Comment: Есть плагины которые добавляют аватар пользователям.

Comment: @Даниил потому что ACF не работает с настройками пользователя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть очень популярный плагин [WP User Avatar](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-user-avatar/). Можно использовать его.